# CTE in stored procedure not working

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I have a stored procedure that is building tables to call later in the query.  I've had to add new table that uses a CTE, but now when I run it with the ; to end the expression, I'm getting an error Incorrect syntax near ';' and when I remove it, I'm getting the error that I need to have a ; with a CTE.  The query itself works outside of the stored procedure.  Any help would be appreciated....

```
set @cdq = 'insert #REMOVAL_FLAG
(
    MYKEY,
    REMOVAL_FLAG
)

    WITH 
create_key AS(
        SELECT *,
        (CONVERT(varchar(25), a.NDC11, 101) + CONVERT(varchar(25), a.PharmacyID, 101) + CONVERT(varchar(50),ABS(a.TotalNetCost),101)) as REVERSAL_KEY

        FROM table1 a

),

find_rev AS (

        SELECT *,
            CASE
                WHEN MIN(TotalAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY REVERSAL_KEY) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL
            END as Flag

        FROM create_key

),

primary_flag as (

        SELECT TOP 1500000 *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY REVERSAL_KEY) as [GROUP],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NDC11, PharmacyID, TotalNetCost ORDER BY REVERSAL_KEY) as PK

        FROM find_rev

        WHERE Flag = 1

        ORDER BY [GROUP], PK
),

flagged as (
        SELECT *,
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT (PK) OVER (PARTITION BY [GROUP], PK) > 1 THEN ''REMOVE''
            END as REMOVAL_FLAG

        FROM primary_flag
)

SELECT a1.MYKEY, f.REMOVAL_FLAG

FROM table1 a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN flagged f ON (f.MYKEY = a1.MYKEY)


'
```

Answer (score 1):

An `insert` statement can use a CTE (`with` expression).  In SQL Server, this goes *before* the `insert`, not before the `select`:

```
WITH 
create_key AS(
        SELECT *,
        (CONVERT(varchar(25), a.NDC11, 101) + CONVERT(varchar(25), a.PharmacyID, 101) + CONVERT(varchar(50),ABS(a.TotalNetCost),101)) as REVERSAL_KEY

        FROM table1 a

),
find_rev AS (
        SELECT *,
            CASE
                WHEN MIN(TotalAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY REVERSAL_KEY) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL
            END as Flag
        FROM create_key
),
primary_flag as (

        SELECT TOP 1500000 *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY REVERSAL_KEY) as [GROUP],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NDC11, PharmacyID, TotalNetCost ORDER BY REVERSAL_KEY) as PK
        FROM find_rev
        WHERE Flag = 1
        ORDER BY [GROUP], PK
),
flagged as (
        SELECT *,
            CASE
                WHEN COUNT (PK) OVER (PARTITION BY [GROUP], PK) > 1 THEN ''REMOVE''
            END as REMOVAL_FLAG
        FROM primary_flag
)
insert #REMOVAL_FLAG(MYKEY, REMOVAL_FLAG)
    SELECT a1.MYKEY, f.REMOVAL_FLAG
    FROM table1 a1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN flagged f ON (f.MYKEY = a1.MYKEY)
```